# Why is my n-body simulation not producing orbits (using Earth and Venus around the Sun)?

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, physics, simulator, astronomy

I am trying to make an n-body simulation in python. I have chosen to test the algorithm on a 3-body system, consisting of Earth, Venus, and the Sun, over a duration of 10 years using a time-step of one day. My algorithm will run to completion, but the output does not seem correct; I am expecting Earth and Venus to have nearly circular paths around the Sun; the actual output is shown below:

[image: This output is wrong]

I am hoping someone can show me either where my implementation is wrong or where my logic is wrong. The implementation is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # view 3d

class CelestialBody():

    def __init__(self, identifier, facecolor, mass, position, velocity=None, acceleration=None, notes=None):
        """ """
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.facecolor = facecolor
        self.mass = mass
        self.position = np.array(position, dtype=float)
        self.velocity = self.autocorrect_parameter(velocity)
        self.acceleration = self.autocorrect_parameter(acceleration)
        self._previous_positions = [self.position]
        self._previous_velocities = [self.velocity]
        self._previous_accelerations = [self.acceleration]
        self.notes = notes

    @property
    def previous_positions(self):
        return np.array(self._previous_positions)

    @property
    def previous_velocities(self):
        return np.array(self._previous_velocities)

    @property
    def previous_accelerations(self):
        return np.array(self._previous_accelerations)

    def autocorrect_parameter(self, args):
        """ """
        if args is None:
            return np.zeros(self.position.shape, dtype=float)
        else:
            return np.array(args, dtype=float)
```

From the class defined above, we can instantiate `Earth`, `Venus`, and the `Sun`. Mass is given in units of kg, positions in meters, velocity in m/s, acceleration in m/s^2. The Sun is initially located at the origin; the initial position of Earth is completely in the x-direction (with its velocity directed in the y-direction, tangential ...); and the initial position of Venus is completely in the y-direction (with is velocity directed in the x-direction). The values used are [obtained and converted via wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=venus%20orbital%20speed).

```
Sun = CelestialBody(identifier='Sun', facecolor='yellow', mass=1.988e30, position=[0, 0, 0])
Earth = CelestialBody(identifier='Earth', facecolor='blue', mass=5.972e24, position=[1.496e11, 0, 0], velocity=[0, 29766.5, 0])
Venus = CelestialBody(identifier='Venus', facecolor='darkorange', mass=4.867e24, position=[0, 1.082e11, 0], velocity=[34995.75, 0, 0])
```

Below is the method to run the simulation. First, a for-loop is used to continually sum the acceleration caused by the force of the `j-th` mass onto the `i-th` mass over the distance that separates them (where `i =/= j`). From the net acceleration, velocity is obtained by multiplying the acceleration with the time-step; the position is calculated by multiplying the velocity with the time-step. This happens for each time-step in the outer loop; for each time-step, the newly calculated position, velocity, and acceleration are appended into their respective attributes of the class `CelestialBody`.

```
class NBodySimulation():

    def __init__(self, bodies, gravitational_constant=6.67e-11, t=0):
        """ """
        self.bodies = bodies
        self.gravitational_constant = gravitational_constant
        self.t = t
        self.collision_times = []

    def update_accelerations(self):
        """ """
        for ith_body, ibody in enumerate(self.bodies):
            ibody.acceleration *= 0
            for jth_body, jbody in enumerate(self.bodies):
                if ith_body != jth_body:
                    # dpos = ibody.position - jbody.position
                    dpos = jbody.position - ibody.position
                    r = np.sum(dpos**2)
                    acc = -1 * self.gravitational_constant * jbody.mass * dpos / np.sqrt(r**3)
                    ibody.acceleration += acc
            ibody._previous_accelerations.append(ibody.acceleration)
            self.bodies[ith_body] = ibody

    def update_velocities_and_positions(self, dt):
        """ """
        for ith_body, ibody in enumerate(self.bodies):
            ibody.velocity += ibody.acceleration * dt
            ibody.position += ibody.velocity * dt
            ibody._previous_velocities.append(ibody.velocity)
            ibody._previous_positions.append(ibody.position)
            self.bodies[ith_body] = ibody

    def run_simulation(self, dt, duration):
        """ """
        nsteps = int(duration / dt)
        for ith_step in range(nsteps):
            self.update_accelerations()
            self.update_velocities_and_positions(dt)
            self.t += dt


    def view_positions(self):
        """ """
        if self.bodies[0].position.size == 2:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ndim = 2
        elif self.bodies[0].position.size == 3:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
            ndim = 3
        npos = len(self.bodies[0].previous_positions)
        for ibody in self.bodies:
            if ndim == 2:
                ax.plot(ibody.previous_positions[0, :], ibody.previous_positions[1, :], color=ibody.facecolor, label=ibody.identifier, alpha=0.5)
            else:
                ax.plot(ibody.previous_positions[0, :], ibody.previous_positions[1, :], ibody.previous_positions[2, :], color=ibody.facecolor, label=ibody.identifier, alpha=0.5)
        # ax.view_init(azim=60, elev=45)
        fig.legend(mode='expand', loc='lower center',     ncol=len(self.bodies))
        plt.show()
        plt.close(fig)
```

To run the code,

```
bodies = [Sun, Earth, Venus]
dt = 86400 # seconds in one day
duration = 315360000 # seconds in 10 years
NB = NBodySimulation(bodies)
NB.run_simulation(dt, duration)
NB.view_positions()
```

Is my output incorrect because of faulty implementation or faulty logic? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I suspect the issue might lie in your `update_accelerations` function. Specifically in between calculating `dpos` and the `acc`. You could normalize `dpos` and then get rid of the `r**3` (in favor of an `r**2`) in the `acc = ...` line.

Comment: @AndrewF Could you explain a little more please? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by normalize; `dpos` is for the directional component and `r` is for the total distance.

Comment: You are printing the wrong numbers. You want `ibody.previous_positions[:, 0]` and not `ibody.previous_positions[0, :]`. Moreover, if you want to "save" a numpy array you need to explicitly copy it. Lines like `ibody._previous_velocities.append(ibody.velocity)` should read `ibody._previous_velocities.append(np.copy(ibody.velocity))`

Comment: @lr1985 That wasn't my only bug, but using `np.copy(...)` helped me fix the code. Thanks. Though I am curious, why doesn't simply appending the array into a list without copying it work?

Comment: Python lists store [references](https://www.quora.com/Does-Python-list-store-pointers-to-the-actual-array-items) and not values.